# Pair wise permutation of two lists in Python

Tags: python-3.x, statistics

I have a list with 10 numerical values. I want to return all possible combination of this list such that each element can take value +/- element value.

The approach I had in mind was to take a binary variable which takes in value from 0 to 1023. 1 in this variable corresponds to positive d[i] and 0 to negative d[i].
e.g. for bin(8) = 0000001000 implies that d7 will take value -d7 and rest will be positive. Repeat this for all 0 to 1023 to get all combinations.

For example, if D = [d1,d2,...d10], we will have 1024 (2^10) combinations such that:

```
    D1 = [-d1,d2,d3,....d10]
    D2 = [-d1,-d2,d3,....d10]
    D3 = [d1,-d2,d3,....d10] ...
    D1024 = [-d1,-d1,-d3,....-d10]
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just use the builtin [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to make all combinations of positive and negative values.

```py
from itertools import product
inputs = list(range(10))  # [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
outputs = []
choices = [(x,-x) for x in inputs]
for item in product(*choices):
    outputs.append(item)
print(outputs[:3])
print(len(outputs))
# [(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, -9), (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, -8, 9)]
# 1024
```

in a compressed form:

```py
outputs = [item for item in product(*[(x,-x) for x in inputs])]
```

Comment: Thank a lot. If I understand it correctly, outputs[:1024] will contain all the possible outcomes.

Comment: @AnuragShukla don't slice the array, `outputs` has all the result, it's just too long to print